# How to Save 2 different Cell values into 2 different variables from database C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am stuck on collecting 2 column values from a database row.
this method is only working to retrieve one value, not for 2. I need to save values from cells to Different variables then I will use these variables to populate another database.

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True";
using (var con2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    try
    {
        con2.Open();             
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = con2;
        command.CommandText = string.Format("update Inventory set Quantity= Quantity - {0} WHERE id='"+tbItemid.Text+"'", Convert.ToInt32(tbQuantity.Text));
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con2.Close();
        Data();
        DData();
        con2.Open();
        int x = int.Parse(tbQuantity.Text);
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT Model from Inventory WHERE id='" + tbItemid.Text + "'", con2);
        SqlDataReader modelRdr = null;
        modelRdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        modelRdr.Read();
        modelRdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        string model = modelRdr["model"].ToString();
        con2.Close();
        con.Open();
        int y = int.Parse(tbQuantity.Text);
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT Price from Inventory WHERE id='" + tbItemid.Text + "'", con2);
        SqlDataReader pricerdr = null;
        pricerdr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
        pricerdr.Read();
        int price = int.Parse(pricerdr["Price"].ToString());
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Bill values (" + tbItemid.Text + ",'"  +model.ToString()+ "',"+price.ToString()+",'"+tbQuantity.Text+"')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        Data();
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter Catagory and Product ID");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first you should use **Parameterized Queries** instead of Concatenations. These kind of queries are prone to **SQL Injection**. You can read both the columns in one command

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT Model, Price from Inventory WHERE id='" + tbItemid.Text + "'", con2);
SqlDataReader modelRdr = null;
modelRdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
modelRdr.Read();
modelRdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
string model = modelRdr["model"].ToString();
int price = int.Parse(modelRdr["Price"].ToString());
```

The complete code with Parameters would look like

```
string model=String.Empty;
int price = 0;
string connectionString = @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True";
using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    try
    {
        con2.Open();             
        using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = con2;
            command.CommandText = string.Format("update Inventory set Quantity = Quantity - @qty WHERE id=@id";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", tbItemid.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", Convert.ToInt32(tbQuantity.Text)));
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Data();
            DData();

            int x = int.Parse(tbQuantity.Text);
            using(SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT Model, Price from Inventory WHERE id=@id"))
            {
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", tbItemid.Text);
                SqlDataReader modelRdr = null;
                modelRdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                modelRdr.Read();
                model = modelRdr["model"].ToString();
                price = int.Parse(modelRdr["Price"].ToString());    
            }
            using(SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into Bill values (@id,@model,@price,@qty)";.
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", tbItemid.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@model", model);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", price);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", tbQuantity.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            Data();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter Catagory and Product ID");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Additional information: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

Comment: this exception is coming

Comment: ah Sorry i am very new to Sql and C# can you tell me what is that(Parameterized Queries )